# Arena simulation export report using VBA

Tags: vba, report, arena-simulation

I'm writing VBA to create, run, export result. I has done with create and run model, But I don't know how to get report result. Example:
- Number out        : 
- Average Queue time: 
- Transfer time

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Thank for response, I found the answer by some code as below: <p> i = s.SymbolNumber("Entity 1")
        j = s.EntitiesNumberOutOfType(i)
    entity_out(n) = j
        ' Current NumberOfQueue
        i = s.SymbolNumber("Process 1.Queue")
        j = s.QueueNumberOfEntities(i)
    entity_queue_1(n) = j </p>

Comment: Great work! You should post your answer as an answer to your question so others can easily recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I try this code, and it work for me

`i = s.SymbolNumber("Entity 1")
 j = s.EntitiesNumberOutOfType(i) 
entity_out(n) = j 
' Current NumberOfQueue 
 i = s.SymbolNumber("Process 1.Queue")
 j = s.QueueNumberOfEntities(i) 
entity_queue_1(n) = j`